# Get correlation form big collection in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, statistics, bigdata

How do I get correlation of a very large collection of data? I couldn't do this approach, https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/ml-statistics.html, because the data I am working with couldn't be loaded to memory all at once.

Thank you

Comment: did you try to run it because it is not necessary that all the data to be loaded to memory at once.

Comment: What do yo mean @AnkitKumarNamdeo? I have a big collection and I want to count the correlation of some of the columns. I can not load all the data to memory, so what options do I have? Thank you